# Select all previous dates and select all dates within 6 months using mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a mysql table which would keep track of drug expiry dates.

***DrugExpiry*** table:

```
drugid, expiry_date
3       2016-08-10
2       2016-10-12
```

Now I want to select all expired drugs and all the drugs that are going to expire within six months.

I have tried the following select, but it does not work as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM lm_products 
        WHERE expiry_date= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
        AND expiry_date<=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This select returns an empty row. Where do I go wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the right comparisons.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM lm_products 
WHERE expiry_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

In other words, you want everything whose expiry date is earlier than six months in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple logic,

```
 SELECT * FROM lm_products 
 WHERE expiry_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

No need DATE_SUB for this, add current date for six months and compare with expiry_date